# Problems with jQuery animations when using auto-pager

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, infinite-scroll

I have an auto-pager set up on my page to allow for infinite scrolling. I also used jQuery to change the opacity of images when they're hovered over. however, the animation only works on the first page, not the consecutive pages that are automatically loaded. any idea why this happens? or are there any methods of fixing this? thanks.

this is the code i'm using for the images and the auto-pager:

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".post").animate({opacity:.8});
$(".post").hover(function(){$(this).stop().animate({opacity:1}, "fast");}, function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity:.8}, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/q0etgkr/J5bl3lkz1/tumblrautopagernopage.js"></script>`

Comment: Nobody will be able to answer this effectively without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Where are your codes? We're not magicians...

To the extent of trying to figure out what you're saying here, I think there's a huge possibility that your code is not applying to the newer, auto-paged ones. See if you could put a more dynamic code into your system, and apply that AFTER the auto-pager has loaded the images.